# Getting an error while importing the database from local to live server

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

i am getting an error while importing  database from local to live server,
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `ss`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `ss` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'secwebs'@'%' to database 'ss'
```

Can somebody please guide me how can i resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a database on the live server, you must have created a username and password on the webhost/provider for the specific database. you will have to edit the wp-config.php file to the new database name/user name/password in order to gain access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is when exporting the database, first of all select the database you want to export then go to the export tab and select all the 'tables of the database' to export it. Instead of exporting the whole database. export just the tables in the database.
Your export is trying to create the database as it is in your local server instead of just creating the tables and populating it on the database you've already created on your live server.
I hope that wasn't confusing.